# Table Adapter error with where clause

Tags: c#, mysql, tableadapter

I am using a table adapter to query a MySQL database, I have query which works fine mysql workbench.

When I add the query to the table adapter I get the following error

> Error in list of function arguments '1' not recognised`and`Error in list of function arguments '0' not recognised`also`Error in list of function arguments 'AS' not recognised

Query

```
SELECT
 a.*,
 at.AuditTypeName,
 s.StaffForename,
 s.StaffSurname
FROM Audits a LEFT JOIN AuditTypes at ON a.AuditTypeID = at.AuditTypeID
 LEFT JOIN Staff s ON a.StaffID = s.StaffID
WHERE date(a.AuditDate) BETWEEN CAST(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB((DATE_SUB(Now(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), INTERVAL 0 DAY) ,'%Y-%m-01') as DATE) AND Now()
ORDER BY a.AuditID DESC
```

Comment: Can you give us the code for adapter  in c#?

Comment: What do you mean by this? I haven't been able to add the adapter in

Comment: The code that produces the exception

Comment: I use the wizard in VS 2017 to help set it up